# how can read text data from excel in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i want to read text and numbers from an excel file. when i write the code as below it can not read the text data from excel file. how can i fix it? thank for taking your time.

```
data = xlsread('normalize.xlsx');
```

the picture of excel file is here:
[image]
    and the picture of data that created from the code is hear:
[image]

Comment: Did you think to export the file as .csv file from Excel, and then use csvread(.csv) to import it from matlab  ?

Answer (score 1):

'xlsread' and 'csvread' are both for reading **numeric data** in MATLAB.  If you are on a Windows platform and have Microsoft Excel installed, you can use the following syntax with 'xlsread' to read your data into two cell arrays:

```
[num_data string_data] = xlsread('normalize.xlsx');
```

You will have the text column in your data in the string_data array. The corresponding column in num_data will still have NAN.

Comment: i want  to use the column of string data as key for inner joining to another data file.in this way it will put in two diffrerent tables and cannot join together.

Comment: You can still join the two arrays together. They correspond with each other column-wise you just need to make a cell array with different columns. In the cell array you can have different type of data for each column